# GCC Warning forming offset [X1, X2] is out of the bounds [0, X3]

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++17

I have the following code to copy one raw (not null terminated) string into const-size char array, but when I compile I get a warning. Could please someone help me to understand what's wrong with this peace of code?

```
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

char reason_[20];

template <size_t N>
void CopyStr(char(&out)[N], const std::string_view& in)
{
    memcpy(out, in.data(), std::min(in.size(), N));
    if (in.size() < N)
        out[in.size()] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    CopyStr(reason_, "User request");
}
```

g++-8 -O3 -mavx -m64 -std=c++17 -g0 -DNDEBUG -fconcepts -Wall test.cpp

```
In function ‘void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)’,
inlined from ‘void CopyStr(char (&)[N], const string_view&) [with long unsigned int N = 20]’ at test.cpp:9:11,
inlined from ‘int main()’ at test.cpp:16:12:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:34:33: warning: ‘void* __builtin_memcpy(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)’ forming offset [14, 20] is out of the bounds [0, 13] [-Warray-bounds]
return __builtin___memcpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos0 (__dest));
```

The following is output of `g++-8 --version`

```
g++ (GCC) 8.3.1 20190311 (Red Hat 8.3.1-3)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

No warnings for

```
clang version 9.0.0-2 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

No warnings for

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me (I would guess the optimizer made some transformation and then the array bounds checker found the transformation had the bounds error). Seeing as it doesn't happen in a later version of g++, a reasonable assumption would be that the bug is fixed

Comment: BTW the code  checks the length twice (your `< N` and the one implied by `std::min`, maybe rewriting it to avoid this will help the optimizer out

Comment: Off-topic: conditionally adding a terminating `'\0'` is sub-optimal (as noted my @M.M) and causes confusion IMO. Either always add it by using `std::min(in.size(), N - 1)`, or never add it.

Comment: Assuming I have char s[3], with s[0] = '1', s[1] = '2', s[2]  ='3'.
reason_ should either be null terminated or 20 elements in length. 
How can I copy my 's' into reason_ in that case?